# working of Reduce() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
In [1]: a = [4,5,6]

In [2]: reduce(lambda x,y:x,a)
Out[2]: 4

In [3]: reduce(lambda x,y:x+1,a)
Out[3]: 6

In [4]: reduce(lambda x,y:x+2,a)
Out[4]: 8

In [5]: reduce(lambda x,y:x+3,a)
Out[5]: 10
```

I understand first reduce operation but I'm getting confused with rest 3 lines.
for 2nd reduce `reduce(lambda x,y:x+1,a)` output should be 5,shouldn't it?
I've already read the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce but didn't get it.

```
In [6]: reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,a)
Out[6]: 15
```

this is alright!No doubt.

Comment: Why do you think the output should be 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 6 because the value "first argument plus one" is evaluated twice, once when the second argument is 5 and once when the second argument is 6.

Answer (score 8):

Reduce in Python

as per python docs
*`Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`*

**Reducing a List**

The function reduce(func, seq) continually applies the function func() to the sequence seq. It returns a single value.

If `seq = [ s1, s2, s3, ... , sn ]`, calling `reduce(func, seq)` works like this:

- At first the first two elements of seq will be applied to func, i.e. func(s1,s2) The list on which reduce() works looks now like this: `[ func(s1, s2), s3, ... , sn ]`
- In the next step func will be applied on the previous result and the third element of the list, i.e. func(func(s1, s2),s3)
  The list looks like this now: `[ func(func(s1, s2),s3), ... , sn ]`
- Continue like this until just one element is left and return this element as the result of reduce()

small demo :
consider `reduce(lambda x,y:x,a)` and compare with  diagram

[image]

let us think reduce loop on your list  `a`:

- first batch we have two values `x,y = 4,5` but lambda is returning only 4 so now 4
- second batch we have perious `4 and 6` it return only 4 . so it is 4

similarly for 2:

[image]

in second diagram ..

- first we have `4,5` as x,y values but return only x+1 ie `4+1=5`
- second we have `5,6` as x,y values but returns only x+1 ie `5+1=6`

Comment: This would be a better answer if the diagram matched the calls in the posted question.

Comment: The original *looked* nicer :), but these I think these are easier to apply to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument `x` to the lambda is the *accumulated* value; the second argument `y` is an element from the list. (If you don't specify an initializer, then the first time the function is called, `x` and `y` are the first two items of the list.) Taking `reduce(lambda x,y:x+1,[4,5,6])` as an example, the following calls to the function are made:

1. `x=4` (the first item in the list) and `y=5` (the second item in the list). The return value of `4+1=5` is used as the accumulated value for the next call.
2. `x=5` and `y=6`. The return value of `5+1=6` is used as the accumulated value for the next call.

Since there are no more items in the list, the return value of the `reduce` function is the most recent accumulated value of 6.